# How to install docker-maven-plugin-0.36.1.jar on Intellij Idea while I select install plugin from disk?

Tags: docker, maven, intellij-idea, plugins, jar

I ran across the problem and installed that plugin from disk on Intellij Idea. The plugin that I would like to install from the disk is docker-maven-plugin jar file downloaded from maven central repository. The error message showed is "Fail to load plugin descriptor from file docker-maven-plugin-0.36.1.jar" while I was installing that jar file from disk. Any help will be appreciated in advance.

docker-maven-plugin version :0.36.1
Maven version:Apache Maven 3.0.5 (Red Hat 3.0.5-17)
Java version: 1.8.0_292, vendor: Red Hat, Inc.
Docker version :Docker version 20.10.8
OS: Centos 7 on Virtualbox

Comment: First I suggest to use a much more recent version of Maven...because 3.0.5 is 7 years old (and EoL https://maven.apache.org/docs/history.html)... please upgrade which I suppose is the reason for the issue... Checked the docker-maven-plugin and it is build with newer version...which is what I expected...so you have to upgrade to 3.8.1  (most recent)..

Comment: That way does not work for me. I have upgraded to 3.8.1 on the terminal end of Centos and also upgraded to 3.8.1 in IntelliJ Idea. Same message will pop up.

Comment: Full working example on github or alike is necessary to see what's really happening... apart from that are you in a corporate environment? What about firewall/proxy etc.?

Comment: Verify that plug-in is packaged correctly, there must be valid `META-INF/plugin.xml` file inside the jar. And the jar must be not corrupted.

Comment: When do you get this error? Does the same command/maven goal work from the OS terminal?

Comment: I have already figured out. Docker-maven-plugin is maven type plugin, which is not capable to be installed from disk on Idea. It is deposited in your Maven local repository and Maven can use it by its pom.xml file and my project's pom file.